# Meaning of complement of vertex and edge sets

Tags: graph-theory, notation

I am reading about maximum bipartite matching and everywhere I look there is thing:
$$
U':=U\setminus M
$$
Sometimes it's written like this:
$$
U':=U\setminus\cup M
$$
where $U$ is a set of vertices and $M$ is a set of edges. What in the world is the result of this operation? You can see it in page 10 of this file:
http://www.st.ewi.tudelft.nl/~roos/courses/WI4064/week2_sl.pdf

Comment: Where you had $U\backslash M$ I changed it to $U\setminus M$.  That is standard.

Comment: From context I think it is just a sloppy way of meaning the vertices in $U$ that are left unmatched by an edge of $M$. Not quite sure though.